# Update gcc alternatives in Ubuntu 18.04 - g++ cannot be slave of gcc

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

Trying to update alternatives but get this error. Googling doesn't show up any solutions.

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
>
> update-alternatives: error: alternative g++ can't be slave of gcc: it
> is a master alternative

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be intended behaviour, but may differ in some releases of Ubuntu.
So in order to avoid that issue for `g++`:

`update-alternatives: error: alternative g++ can't be slave of gcc: it is a master alternative`

simply call it up individually in `update-alternatives`, e.g.:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 110`

Be aware to have this maybe in sync with the other GNU tools.

It seems not to be an issue in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for `g++`, but for `cpp` nevertheless, so in order to avoid that issue for `cpp` there:

`update-alternatives: error: alternative cpp can't be slave of gcc: it is a master alternative`

for instance in the case of upgrading from `gcc-9` to `gcc-11` and to keep the other alternatives in sync, the following worked under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gcc-11 g++-11 cpp-11
```

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 90 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-9 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-9 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-9 && \
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp /usr/bin/cpp-9 90
```

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 110 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-11 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-11 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11 && \
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp /usr/bin/cpp-11 110
```

Validation might be done via:

```
gcc --version;g++ --version;gcov --version;cpp --version;
```

**Edit:**

For the interested, upgrading the `gdb` in this context has the following steps:

```
gdbVersion=11.1
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-${gdbVersion}.tar.xz
tar -xf gdb-${gdbVersion}.tar.xz
cd gdb-${gdbVersion}/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Validation:

```
gdb --version
```

Comment: switching between GCC 11 and 12 works perfectly under Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks a bunch!